# Firebase alert for network error and critical error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have configured the velocity alerts for Crashlytics but is there any way to configure warning and critical alerts for network error and critical errors in firebase console. I use a ReactApplication with cloud functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "critical alerts for network error"? What network errors are you referring to? Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure warning and critical alerts for network error and critical errors in the Firebase console, even if you are using a ReactApplication with cloud functions.

1. Set up Google Cloud Monitoring: Create a Google Cloud Monitoring
   project and enable the Monitoring API. This will allow you to send
   logs and metrics from your Firebase project to Cloud Monitoring.
2. Deploy a Cloud Function: Deploy a Cloud Function that will
   periodically query your Firebase project's Crashlytics data for
   network errors and critical errors. The Cloud Function should then
   send this data to Cloud Monitoring as metrics.
3. Create Alert Policies: Create alert policies in Cloud Monitoring
   that will trigger when the network error or critical error metrics
   exceed certain thresholds. These alerts can then notify you via
   email, SMS, or other channels.

Here is an example of a Cloud Function that you can use to send network error and critical error data to Cloud Monitoring:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const monitoring = require('@google-cloud/monitoring');

admin.initializeApp();
const client = new monitoring.MetricServiceClient();

exports.monitorCrashlytics = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const projectId = '[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]';
  const now = new Date();

  const crashlytics = admin.crashlytics();
  crashlytics.getIssues().then(issues => {
    const networkErrors = issues.filter(issue => issue.issueType === 'network');
    const criticalErrors = issues.filter(issue => issue.issueSeverity === 'critical');

    const metricData = {
      type: 'custom.googleapis.com/firebase/crashlytics/network_errors',
      metricKind: 'INT64',
      valueType: 'INT64',
      points: [{
        interval: { endTime: { seconds: now.getTime() / 1000 } },
        value: { int64Value: networkErrors.length }
      }]
    };

    client.createTimeSeries({
      name: `projects/${projectId}/metrics`,
      timeSeries: [metricData]
    }).then(() => {
      const metricData = {
        type: 'custom.googleapis.com/firebase/crashlytics/critical_errors',
        metricKind: 'INT64',
        valueType: 'INT64',
        points: [{
          interval: { endTime: { seconds: now.getTime() / 1000 } },
          value: { int64Value: criticalErrors.length }
        }]
      };

      client.createTimeSeries({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/metrics`,
        timeSeries: [metricData]
      }).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send('OK');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here is an example of an alert policy for network errors:

```
{
 "name": "NetworkErrorsAlert",
  "displayName": "Network Errors Alert",
  "type": "metricAlert",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "type": "custom.googleapis.com/firebase/crashlytics/network_errors"
      },
      "expression": "value.int64Value > 100",
      "duration": "600s"
    }
  ],
  "policy": {
    "notificationChannels": [
      {
        "type": "email",
        "emailAddresses": ["user@example.com"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This alert policy will trigger an email notification if the number of network errors exceeds 100 in the past 10 minutes. You can create similar alert policies for critical errors.